# where is error number of ::accept from socket.h

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, error-handling, throw

Here is what I have so far

```
socklen_t cli_size;
struct sockaddr cli;
int in_sock;

/* event from TCP server socket, new connection */
cli_size = sizeof(cli);
try {
    if ((in_sock  = ::accept(handle,&cli, &cli_size)) < 0) {
        throw in_sock;
        return NULL;
        }
    }
catch(int ex) {
    cout << "Exception Nr. " << ex << endl;
    }
```

from man page:

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

Question: I still can't understand where is errno? I need to understand exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`errno` is a global integer variable that contains error codes after system calls like `accept` fails. You might have to include the header file `<errno.h>` for the variable to be defined.

In your case, you shouldn't throw the value returned by `accept` but the value of `errno`:

```
try
{
    if ((in_sock = accept(...)) == -1)
        throw errno;
    // ...
}
catch (int error)
{
    std::cout << "Error code " << error << " (" << std::strerror(error) << ")\n";
}
```

The function [`std::strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) is declared in the header file `<cstring>` and returns a string describing the error.

An important note: The value of `errno` is only valid **if** a function returns that it failed. If, in your example, `accept` succeeds then the value of `errno` is undefined.

Comment: thank you, approve after 5 minutes. Result: Error code 24 (Too many open files) ... wow, it's something I can't understand :) sockets... files...

Comment: @МарияШарапова Remember that in Unix systems (like Linux) a socket is just another file descriptor, and uses the same tables as normal files. This error means you either have lots (over 1000) connections and/or files open, which might indicate that you don't close connections and/or file properly after use.